# MySQL Error 1093 - Can't specify target table for update in FROM clause

Tags: mysql, subquery, sql-delete, mysql-error-1093

I have a table `story_category` in my database with corrupt entries. The next query returns the corrupt entries:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  story_category 
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category.id 
    FROM category INNER JOIN 
       story_category ON category_id=category.id);
```

I tried to delete them executing:

```
DELETE FROM story_category 
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category.id 
    FROM category 
      INNER JOIN story_category ON category_id=category.id);
```

But I get the next error:

> #1093 - You can't specify target table 'story_category' for update in FROM clause

How can I overcome this?

Comment: Related:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14302701/238419

Comment: Seems like the feature request in the MySQL bug tracker is here: [cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=23353)

Comment: [MariaDB 10.3 allows for self-referencing in UPDATE/DELETE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50749204/5070879)

Answer (score 960, accepted):

*Update: This answer covers the general error classification. For a more specific answer about how to best handle the OP's exact query, please see other answers to this question*

In MySQL, you can't modify the same table which you use in the SELECT part.
This behaviour is documented at:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html

**Maybe you can just join the table to itself**

If the logic is simple enough to re-shape the query, lose the subquery and join the table to itself, employing appropriate selection criteria. This will cause MySQL to see the table as two different things, allowing destructive changes to go ahead.

```
UPDATE tbl AS a
INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON ....
SET a.col = b.col
```

**Alternatively, try nesting the subquery deeper into a from clause ...**

If you absolutely need the subquery, there's a workaround, but it's
ugly for several reasons, including performance:

```
UPDATE tbl SET col = (
  SELECT ... FROM (SELECT.... FROM) AS x);
```

The nested subquery in the FROM clause creates an *implicit temporary
table*, so it doesn't count as the same table you're updating.

**... but watch out for the query optimiser**

However, beware that from [MySQL 5.7.6](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/mysql/5.7/en/news-5-7-6.html) and onward, the optimiser may optimise out the subquery, and still give you the error. Luckily, the  `optimizer_switch` variable can be used to switch off this behaviour; although I couldn't recommend doing this as anything more than a short term fix, or for small one-off tasks.

```
SET optimizer_switch = 'derived_merge=off';
```

*Thanks to [Peter V. Mørch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/345716/peter-v-m%C3%B8rch) for this advice in the comments.*

Example technique was from Baron Schwartz, [originally published at Nabble](http://grokbase.com/t/mysql/mysql/08259dm24b/error-you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause), paraphrased and extended here.

Comment: Upvoted this answer because I had to delete items and could not get info from another table, had to subquery from same table. Since this is what pops up on top while googling for the error I got this would be the best fit answer for me and a lot of people trying to update while subquerieing from the same table.

Comment: @Cheekysoft, Why not save the values into variables instead?

Comment: @PeterV.Mørch Following http://mysqlserverteam.com/derived-tables-in-mysql-5-7, in case certain operations are carried out, merging cannot happen. E.g. provide the derived dummy table with a LIMIT (to inifity) and the error will never occur. That's pretty hackish though and there is still the risk that future versions of MySQL will support merging queries with LIMIT after all.

Comment: Can you, please, provide a full example about this workaround? 
UPDATE tbl SET col = ( SELECT ... FROM (SELECT.... FROM) AS x); i'm still getting errors

Comment: INNER JOIN Work for me :)

Comment: @Cheekysoft could you please help me to find out where I'm doing wrong?


<br><br>

"update tmp_beneficiary as a
    inner join tmp_beneficiary b on a.id = b.id
set a.photo = b.photo
where a.id in (5, 13, 84)
  and b.id = 1;"

Comment: Might be a bit late but self joining the table works for my conditional query as well

Answer (score 567):

[NexusRex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/445500/nexusrex) provided  a [very good solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8620162/1101589) for deleting with join from the same table.

If you do this:

```
DELETE FROM story_category
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
        SELECT DISTINCT category.id AS cid FROM category 
        INNER JOIN story_category ON category_id=category.id
)
```

you are going to get an error.

But if you wrap the condition in one more select:

```
DELETE FROM story_category
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT cid FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT category.id AS cid FROM category 
        INNER JOIN story_category ON category_id=category.id
    ) AS c
)
```

it would do the right thing!!

**Explanation:** The query optimizer does a [*derived merge optimization*](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/derived-table-merge-optimization/) for the first query (which causes it to fail with the error), but the second query doesn't qualify for the *derived merge optimization*. Hence the optimizer is forced to execute the subquery first.

Comment: This worked great, thanks!  So what's the logic here?  If it's nested one more level then it will be executed before the outer part?  And if it's not nested then mySQL tries to run it after the delete has a lock on the table?

Comment: This error and solution make no logical sense...but it works. Sometimes I wonder what drugs the MySQL devs are on...

Comment: @ekonoval Thanks you for the solution but It does not make the minimum sense for me, looks like you is fooling MySQL and he accept it, lol

Comment: The query optimizer does a [_derived merge optimization_](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/derived-table-merge-optimization/) for the first query (which causes it to fail with the error), but the second query doesn't qualify for the _derived merge optimization_ hence the optimizer is forced to execute the subquery first. **Neat solution!**

Comment: I already had the statement wrapped in a second select statement, but when I added a third one it worked. Perhaps this proves that Oracle have a sense of humour??

Comment: Saved me a load of time here, thank you for the clear and concise answer.

Answer (score 122):

The `inner join` in your sub-query is unnecessary.  It looks like you want to delete the entries in `story_category` where the `category_id` is not in the `category` table.

Instead of that:

```
DELETE FROM story_category 
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category.id 
    FROM category INNER JOIN
         story_category ON category_id=category.id);
```

Do this:

```
DELETE FROM story_category 
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category.id 
    FROM category);
```

Comment: I think `DISTINCT` is unnecessary here - for a better performance ;).

Comment: I must be crazy.  The answer is the same as what was stated in the original.

Comment: This is the answer for me also. Don't `where in` on the ID column, so you dont need to subquery the primary table.

Answer (score 121):

Recently i had to update records in the same table i did it like below:

```
UPDATE skills AS s, (SELECT id  FROM skills WHERE type = 'Programming') AS p
SET s.type = 'Development' 
WHERE s.id = p.id;
```

Comment: Can't this just be written as `UPDATE skills SET type='Development' WHERE type='Programming';` ? This doesn't seem to be answering the original question.

Comment: Seems like overkill, @lilbyrdie is correct - it could only be `UPDATE skills SET type='Development' WHERE type='Programming';`. I do not understand why so many people is not thinking about what they do...

Comment: this is the best answer here, IMHO. It's syntax is easy to understand, you can re-use your previous statement and it's not limited to some super specific case.

Comment: Even if the example case is questionable, the principle is the best to understand and deploy in real-world scenarios. The shown query works because implicit join in table list creates a temporary table for a subquery, thus providing stable results and avoiding clash between retrieval and modification of the same table.

Comment: regardless of what anyone might say about this being overkill, it still answers the question in terms of the title. The error which the OP mentioned is also encountered when a update is attempted using the same table in a nested query

Comment: @AnrDaemon, very usefull features. What about optimization in accessing the temporary table created ? Does it still use the indexes of the original table ?

Comment: @lilbyrdie, Doing as you have shown in your example will throw  `Error Code: 1175. You are using safe update mode and you tried to update a table without a WHERE that uses a KEY column.  To disable safe mode, toggle the option in Preferences -> SQL Editor and reconnect.` And it's the best approach I found without Inner Join. Thank you Pratik.

Comment: For me, it says: "A new statement was found but no delimiter between it and the previous one. (near select)". It seems it doesn't like to see a SELECT there.

Answer (score 110):

If you can't do

```
UPDATE table SET a=value WHERE x IN
    (SELECT x FROM table WHERE condition);
```

because it is the same table, you can trick and do :

```
UPDATE table SET a=value WHERE x IN
    (SELECT * FROM (SELECT x FROM table WHERE condition) as t)
```

[update or delete or whatever]

Answer (score 46):

```
DELETE FROM story_category
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT cid FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT category.id AS cid FROM category INNER JOIN story_category ON category_id=category.id
    ) AS c
)
```

Comment: Can you explain why this works, why just nesting one more level works? This question has been asked already as a comment to @EkoNoval's question but nobody responded. Maybe you can help.

Comment: @AkshayArora, Go through the part under the heading 'Maybe you can just join the table to itself' in @Cheekysoft's answer. He said `UPDATE tbl AS a
INNER JOIN tbl AS b ON ....
SET a.col = b.col` - this would work as a different alias for the same table is used here  . Similarly in @NexusRex's answer the first `SELECT` query acts as a derived table into which `story_category` is used for the second time. So the error mentioned in the OP should not take place here, right ?

Answer (score 20):

For the specific query the OP is trying to achieve, the ideal and most efficient way to do this is NOT to use a subquery at all.

Here are the `LEFT JOIN` versions of the OP's two queries:

```sql
SELECT s.* 
FROM story_category s 
LEFT JOIN category c 
ON c.id=s.category_id 
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

Note: `DELETE s` restricts delete operations to the `story_category` table.
[Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/delete.html#idm45469393574032)

```sql
DELETE s 
FROM story_category s 
LEFT JOIN category c 
ON c.id=s.category_id 
WHERE c.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: Surprised this doesn't have more up-votes. It should also be noted that the multi-table syntax also works with `UPDATE` statements and joined sub-queries. Allowing you to perform `LEFT JOIN ( SELECT ... )` as opposed to `WHERE IN( SELECT ... )`, making the implementation useful across many use-cases.

Answer (score 15):

This is what I did for updating a Priority column value by 1 if it is >=1 in a table and in its WHERE clause using a subquery on same table to make sure that at least one row contains Priority=1 (because that was the condition to be checked while performing update) :

```
UPDATE My_Table
SET Priority=Priority + 1
WHERE Priority >= 1
AND (SELECT TRUE FROM (SELECT * FROM My_Table WHERE Priority=1 LIMIT 1) as t);
```

I know it's a bit ugly but it does works fine.

Comment: You can't modify the same table that you use in the SELECT statement.

Comment: @Chris I have verified it on MySQL and it works just fine for me so I would request you to please verify it at your end and then claim it to be correct or incorrect. Thanks!!!

Comment: At the bottom of this page it says 'Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.'  - and I have experienced this to be true on many occasions.  http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html

Comment: @Chris I know that, but there is a workaround for that and which is exactly what I have tried to show with my 'UPDATE' query and believe me it works just fine. I don't think you have really tried to verify my query at all.

Comment: Unique answer here I used to get working in the case of the `select` returning multiple items and the `where` matches a `IN`. But, in fact, @NexuxRex is the complete example for my case.

Answer (score 9):

The simplest way to do this is use a table alias when you are referring parent query table inside the sub query.

Example :

```
insert into xxx_tab (trans_id) values ((select max(trans_id)+1 from xxx_tab));
```

Change it to:

```
insert into xxx_tab (trans_id) values ((select max(P.trans_id)+1 from xxx_tab P));
```

Answer (score 5):

You could insert the desired rows' ids into a temp table and then delete all the rows that are found in that table.

which may be what @Cheekysoft meant by doing it in two steps.

Answer (score 3):

According to  [the Mysql UPDATE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html) linked by @CheekySoft, it says right at the bottom.

> Currently, you cannot update a table and select from the same table in a subquery.

I guess you are deleting from store_category while still selecting from it in the union.

Answer (score 2):

Try to save result of Select statement in separate variable and then use that for delete query.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
DELETE FROM story_category 
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT category.id 
FROM (SELECT * FROM STORY_CATEGORY) sc;
```

Answer (score 1):

If something does not work, when coming thru the front-door, then take the back-door:

```
drop table if exists apples;
create table if not exists apples(variety char(10) primary key, price int);

insert into apples values('fuji', 5), ('gala', 6);

drop table if exists apples_new;
create table if not exists apples_new like apples;
insert into apples_new select * from apples;

update apples_new
    set price = (select price from apples where variety = 'gala')
    where variety = 'fuji';
rename table apples to apples_orig;
rename table apples_new to apples;
drop table apples_orig;
```

It's fast. The bigger the data, the better.

Comment: And you've just lost all your foreign keys, and maybe you have some cascading deletes, too.

Comment: May be you can use this trick, but updating the original table instead of the new table, so you don't need to do the rename trick...

Answer (score 1):

how about this query hope it helps

```
DELETE FROM story_category LEFT JOIN (SELECT category.id FROM category) cat ON story_category.id = cat.id WHERE cat.id IS NULL
```

Comment: The result shows : ' #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'LEFT JOIN (SELECT categories.id FROM categories) cat ON story_category.id = cat.' at line 1 '

Comment: When using multi-table delete you must specify the affected tables. `DELETE story_category FROM ...` however, the joined sub-query is not necessary in this context and can be performed using `LEFT JOIN category AS cat ON cat.id = story_category.category_id WHERE cat.id IS NULL`, Note the join criteria in the answer incorrectly references `story_category.id = cat.id`

Answer (score 1):

As far as concerns, you want to delete rows in `story_category` that do not exist in `category`.

Here is your original query to identify the rows to delete:

```
SELECT * 
FROM  story_category 
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category.id 
    FROM category INNER JOIN 
       story_category ON category_id=category.id
);
```

Combining `NOT IN` with a subquery that `JOIN`s the original table seems unecessarily convoluted. This can  be expressed in a more straight-forward manner with `not exists` and a correlated subquery:

```
select sc.*
from story_category sc
where not exists (select 1 from category c where c.id = sc.category_id);
```

Now it is easy to turn this to a `delete` statement:

```
delete from story_category
where not exists (select 1 from category c where c.id = story_category.category_id);
```

This quer would run on any MySQL version, as well as in most other databases that I know.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=d73925fbe6a24605b1cf9fe66a94d07c)**:

```
-- set-up
create table story_category(category_id int);
create table category (id int);
insert into story_category values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5);
insert into category values (4), (5), (6), (7);

-- your original query to identify offending rows
SELECT * 
FROM  story_category 
WHERE category_id NOT IN (
    SELECT DISTINCT category.id 
    FROM category INNER JOIN 
       story_category ON category_id=category.id);
```

```
| category_id |
| ----------: |
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           3 |
```

```
-- a functionally-equivalent, simpler query for this
select sc.*
from story_category sc
where not exists (select 1 from category c where c.id = sc.category_id)
```

```
| category_id |
| ----------: |
|           1 |
|           2 |
|           3 |
```

```
-- the delete query
delete from story_category
where not exists (select 1 from category c where c.id = story_category.category_id);

-- outcome
select * from story_category;
```

```
| category_id |
| ----------: |
|           4 |
|           5 |
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit hacky but does work:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE my_table
SELECT * FROM source_table WHERE x = "yz";
```

You can then make the query from the temporary table data

Answer (score 0):

In such a case you can create a [Mysql function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-procedure.html) easily. then put the sub-query inside it and pass the parameters through the function. replace the function to the location where the sub-query was called.

small example. just think you want to calculate the next ID for the next user by incrementing one.

**the way that you got an error.**

```
Insert into user (id,name, age, type) values (((select count(id) from user_table where user_type=?)+1),?,?,?);
```

### Solution

**creating function.**

```sql
DELIMITER //

CREATE FUNCTION getNextNumber(userType varchar(255)) RETURNS INT
BEGIN
    DECLARE currentNumber INT;
    
    -- Calculate the square
    SET currentNumber = select count(id) from user_table where user_type=userType;
    
    -- Increment the count
    SET countValue = currentNumber + 1;

    -- Return the currentNumber 
    RETURN currentNumber ;
END //

DELIMITER ;
```

**calling function where you want.**

```sql
Insert into user (id,name, age, type) values (getNextNumber(?),?,?,?);
```